# how run standard and video line item in same ad unit

Tags: google-dfp

We have a 300 by 250 on the right rail of our site and we have about 5 customers ad rotating (jpg, gif and swf), but one of our customer would like to upload a advertisement video ad I am not sure how to set this up in google double click. Can any one please help.

Many Thanks =)

Comment: I don't think that tag means what you think it means. (Try tagging with the language you're working in and any important concepts, e.g., 'advertising'. Always read the description of a tag before using it so you can be sure you're using it properly.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply we already have it working this tag <div id='div-gpt-ad-1487220158251-22'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1487220158251-22'); });
</script>
</div> but this are only for jpgs gifs and swf, video tags are different and I'm not sure how to set it up we need dfp to host the video (not the pre-roll mid roll etc.)basically having the option to upload jpgs gifs swfs and mp4s

Comment: I meant the [double-click] tag on your post. It's for "the act of pressing a computer mouse button twice quickly", not the advertising platform. If you edit your question, you can remove the current tag and replace it with more relevant ones.

Comment: Oh sorry I was going to change the tag but accidentally forgot too lolz.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Custom creative. Then insert something like this :

```
<a href="%%CLICK_URL_UNESC%%%%DEST_URL%%" target="_blank">
  <video autoplay loop>
  <source src="INSERT VIDEO URL" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</a>
```

You can also upload video to dfp (there is a size limit) and use file macro.